# Python hashlib: TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Tags: python, encryption, hash, encryption-symmetric, hashlib

I am writing a client/server program for class which allows the client to send messages to the server using a variety of different encryption techniques.  Right now, I'm in the middle of implementing symmetric encryption, and the server is throwing me an error when I attempt to hash the public key that it receives from the client during the initial key distribution.  I am not very familiar with these libraries so I'm not quite sure what the cause of this error is.

My server code:

```
from Crypto.Random import *
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import hashlib

import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

c = None
addr = None

s.listen(5)
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()
   print ('Got connection from', addr)
   break
c.send('You have connected to the server.\nPlease select one of the following communication options by entering the corresponding number.\n1. Public Key Encryption\n2. Symmetric Key Encryption\n3. Digital Signature\n4. Hash'.encode('ascii'))
#receive user option, this will get used in code I add in later
option = c.recv(1024).decode()
#receive and process the public key
pKey = RSA.importKey(c.recv(2048).decode())
#receive the original digest
digest = c.recv(2048).decode()
#hash the received key
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(pKey)
newDigest = hash_object.hexdigest()

if newDigest == digest:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")
```

My client code:

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import hashlib
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
inLoop = True

s.connect((host, port))
print(s.recv(1024).decode())
while(True):
    option = input("Select an option: ")
    print(option)
    s.send(option.encode())
    if (option == '1'):
        #Begin handshake
        random = Random.new().read
        key = RSA.generate(1024,random)
        pKey = key.publickey().exportKey()
        hash_object = hashlib.sha1(pKey)
        hex_digest = hash_object.hexdigest()
        #send public key
        s.send(pKey)
        #send digest
        s.send(hex_digest.encode())

    elif(option == 2):
        while(inLoop == True):
            ""
    elif(option == 3):
        while(inLoop == True):
            ""
    elif(option == 4):
        while(inLoop == True):
            ""
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid option.")

s.close()
```

Right now a great deal of this is unfinished, but the **specific** problem I am having is that the client creates a public RSA key, and hashes it, and sends the public key and the hex_digest to the server.  The server receives the public key and decodes it into a string, and then turns it into an RSA key, but hashlib gives me an error once I attempt to hash the key.  When the server reaches the line `hash_object = hashlib.sha1(pKey)`, I receive an error: `TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required`

I am not sure what this means; I've done a lot of research.  I do not know how to fix this, but for some reason the server will not hash the key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.  I was doing `hash_object = hashlib.sha1(pKey)`, but pKey is an RSA key, not a string, so I needed to do `hash_object = hashlib.sha1(pKey.exportKey())` instead.